# Is the behavior of `sprintf` with a `NULL` format string defined?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, c-strings, null-pointer

A junior colleague wrote something like this:

```c
char str[20] = "Normal"; // declared globally

void somefunc(void)
{
  sprintf(str, NULL);
  if (var == TARGET)
  {
    sprintf(str, "Set");
  }
  else
  {
    sprintf(str, "Normal");
  }
}
```

Besides recommending using `snprintf` instead, I was contemplating what `sprintf` would do with a `NULL` format string (in the first line of the func) - not a `NULL` *value* string, but the format control itself. I didn't see anything in documentation I've read.

Is this covered in a standard, or is it perhaps implementation defined? As he's apparently running this code, it must not be causing a segmentation fault here (dereferencing `NULL`), but is that standard? Is there something I can point to that says "Don't do this.", or is it perhaps perfectly safe (by standard/definition)?

At best it seems an unnecessary statement, but at worst I'm concerned another compiler could cause a segfault here...

Comment: [C11 7.1.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4): "1. If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as [...] a null pointer [...]) [...], the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Ruslan is right: if the standard doesn't define what happens, then it's undefined.  The standard defines what happens when the second argument is a pointer to a string.  A NULL pointer doesn't point to anything, so in particular it's not a pointer to a string.

Comment: If you want an sprintf that does nothing, pass an empty string instead: `sprintf(str, "");`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah pmg's comment implies that you cannot pass a NULL pointer to a function that does not allow a NULL pointer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: that comment applies to functions defined in section 7 of the Standard. It does not say anything about user-defined functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a call invokes undefined behavior because (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function; and this is valid for sprintf)

> 3 The format **shall be** a multibyte character sequence...

Comment: Here is a link to [§7.21.6.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) of the official ISO C11 standard. Feel free to incorporate this link into the answer.

Comment: Note that [§7.21.6.6 ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.6p2) states that `fprintf` is equivalent to the `sprintf` function, except for the exceptions mentioned in that section. Therefore, most of what §7.21.6.1 specifies also applies to `sprintf`. The answer already specified this, I just wanted to mention the appropriate section of the C standard for completeness.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: calling [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) "official" may be an exxageration. It's a copy of the draft, formatted for the web, for free reference